# Anti-aliasing like in Safari and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, antialiasing

I've been working on a website and I can't get to make the text look anti-aliased when it's size is small on all the browsers.

I Can see the best results in Safari and Firefox, however, in IE and Chrome the text is anti-aliased in a bad way that it looks thicker than needed.

I've tried all the anti-aliasing solutions I have found but none fits my need.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried plz

Comment: i have tried the folowing 

font-smooth:always;
font-smoothing:antialiased;
-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; 
font-weight:1;

Comment: As an aside, I prefer small text to be aliased because otherwise it's hard to read.

Comment: @Wug, true but i'm using a font that really needs antialiasing , and it's really easy to read on safari.

Comment: What font are you using?